# Django DateTimeField editing in admin site

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have a DateTimeField in a model like this:

```
pickupTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I can create a model entry in the admin site but when I click to edit it, I get the error:

```
'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'date'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the variable name from "pickupTime" to a another name "date" and then after migrations I can edit the model in the admin site. I am guessing the pickupTime column has some old data or something that prevented it from being displayed in the admin site

Answer (score -1):

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    .
    .
    .
    pickupTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

There is always some differences between the python datetime and django timezone modules.try using the Django one

Comment: no no no, never use code like this, value for the default will be evaluated once - during first module import, not during each model instantiation; to be safe is better to use auto_now_add=True